# Convert c# foreach to Linq expression

Tags: c#, linq

I have following code snippet in c# which is working fine

```
foreach (var customer in customers.OrderBy(x => x.CustomerId))
{
    if (customer.CustomerId != customerId)
    {
        winningRate = Helper.Utility.WinningRate(settledCustomers, customer.CustomerId).Status;
        numberOfBets = customers.Count(x => x.CustomerId == customer.CustomerId);
        numberOfWinnings = customers.Count(x => x.CustomerId == customer.CustomerId && x.Win > 0);
        averageBet = Helper.Utility.CustomerAverageBet(settledCustomers, customer.CustomerId);
    }

    var risky = Helper.Utility.CheckRiskyBet(winningRate, numberOfWinnings, numberOfBets, averageBet, customer.Stake, customer.Win);

    customer.Status = risky.Status;
    customer.Message = risky.Message;
    customerId = customer.CustomerId;
}
return customers;
```

Now I want to convert above code into LINQ expression and for the same I have written following code which is not giving the same output as

```
var r = from c in customers
        let winningRate1 = Helper.Utility.WinningRate(settledCustomers, c.CustomerId).Status
        let numberOfBets1 = customers.Count(x => x.CustomerId == c.CustomerId)
        let numberOfWinnings1 = customers.Count(x => x.CustomerId == c.CustomerId && x.Win > 0)
        let averageBet1 = Helper.Utility.CustomerAverageBet(settledCustomers, c.CustomerId)
        let risky1 = Helper.Utility.CheckRiskyBet(winningRate, numberOfWinnings, numberOfBets, averageBet, c.Stake, c.Win)
        where c.CustomerId != customerId
        orderby c.CustomerId
        select new Customer
        {
            Status = risky1.Status,
            Message = risky1.Message,
            CustomerId = c.CustomerId
        };
```

Comment: Why do you want to convert your code? You should group by CustomerId and not use customer.CustomerId != customerId.

Comment: You shouldn't use Linq to modify the elements of a sequence. What's wrong with what you have that works?

Comment: I am just trying to convert to linq there is no problem with current implementation

Comment: Download resharper addon for vs, it will do it for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     where c.CustomerId != customerId
```

This clearly is wrong because it reduces the number of times the loop runs.

---

Many let clauses and control flow in the loop can get ugly when converting to query expressions. A multi-statement lambda often is easier and gets you the same functional code benefits:

```
customers
.OrderBy(x => x.CustomerId)
.Select(c => {
    if (customer.CustomerId != customerId)
    {
        winningRate = Helper.Utility.WinningRate(settledCustomers, customer.CustomerId).Status;
        numberOfBets = customers.Count(x => x.CustomerId == customer.CustomerId);
        numberOfWinnings = customers.Count(x => x.CustomerId == customer.CustomerId && x.Win > 0);
        averageBet = Helper.Utility.CustomerAverageBet(settledCustomers, customer.CustomerId);
    }

    var risky = Helper.Utility.CheckRiskyBet(winningRate, numberOfWinnings, numberOfBets, averageBet, customer.Stake, customer.Win);

    return new Customer
        {
            Status = risky.Status,
            Message = risky.Message,
            CustomerId = c.CustomerId
        };
});
```

This code is just a sketch, it has some issues that you can easily fix. For examples I'm assigning to non-local variables. Your code did not explain what those are so I left them alone.